# Oracle big datafile restore fails using Netbackup (ORA-19511, ORA-27190)

Tags: oracle, backup, restore

I am restoring datafiles about 1000GB in size. I am using Netbackup as a backup server.

After 2 hours reading Netbackup fails with the following error:

```
7/25/2012 3:27:50 PM - Error bpbrm(pid=1176) socket read failed, An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  (10054)
7/25/2012 3:27:50 PM - restored image r2n1_1342889172 - (file read failed(13)); restore time 02:01:41
7/25/2012 3:27:54 PM - end Restore; elapsed time: 02:01:50
the restore failed to recover the requested files(5)
```

RMAN shows the following error:

```
channel ch1_tape: ORA-27192: skgfcls: sbtclose2 returned error - failed to close file
ORA-19511: Error received from media manager layer, error text:
   VxBSAEndTxn: Failed with error:
   The sequence of calls is incorrect.
ORA-19870: error while restoring backup piece 
ORA-19501: read error on file , block number  (block size=512)
ORA-27190: skgfrd: sbtread2 returned error
```

I looked in  ...\NetBackup\logs\bpbrm and found the following:

```
15:03:03.132 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm read_parent_msg: read from parent ACK_KEEP_ALIVE
15:03:11.681 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm read_media_msg: read from media manager: MEDIA NOT READY
15:03:11.681 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm signal_bpbrm_child: sending Media Ready to bpbrm child 1176
15:03:11.681 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm read_media_msg: read from media manager: EXIT r2n1_1342889172 0
15:03:11.681 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm process_media_msg: media manager for backup id r2n1_1342889172 exited with status 0: the requested operation was successfully completed
15:03:11.681 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm signal_bpbrm_child: sending Normal Exit to bpbrm child 1176
15:03:13.787 [1176.2356] <2> bpbrm mm_sig: received not ready signal from media manager
15:08:12.044 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm send_parent_msg: KEEP_ALIVE 20

15:08:12.106 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm read_parent_msg: read from parent ACK_KEEP_ALIVE
15:13:13.061 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm send_parent_msg: KEEP_ALIVE 21

15:13:13.186 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm read_parent_msg: read from parent ACK_KEEP_ALIVE
15:18:14.001 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm send_parent_msg: KEEP_ALIVE 22

15:18:14.063 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm read_parent_msg: read from parent ACK_KEEP_ALIVE
15:23:15.018 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm send_parent_msg: KEEP_ALIVE 23
```

............

```
bpbrm send_parent_msg: CURRENT POSITION C047L4 8
15:26:58.145 [5412.7124] <2> bpbrm read_parent_msg: read from parent CONTINUE RESTORE
15:26:58.145 [5412.7124] <2> bpbrm tell_mm: sending media manager msg: CONTINUE RESTORE
15:26:59.081 [5412.7124] <2> bpbrm read_media_msg: read from media manager: MEDIA READY
15:26:59.081 [5412.7124] <2> bpbrm signal_bpbrm_child: sending Media Ready to bpbrm child 7468
15:27:01.343 [7468.4308] <2> bpbrm mm_sig: received ready signal from media manager
15:27:06.070 [7468.4308] <2> bpbrm handle_restore: from client r2n1t.justice.gov.ge: change timeout to 10800
15:27:50.234 [1176.2356] <16> bpbrm readline: socket read failed, An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  (10054)
15:27:50.265 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm brm_child_done: child done, status 13
15:27:50.265 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm brm_child_done: child 1176 exited with status 13: file read failed
15:27:50.265 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm send_status_to_parent: EXIT r2n1_1342889172 13 sent to parent process.
15:27:50.327 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm read_parent_msg: read from parent TERMINATE
15:27:50.327 [660.7908] <2> bpbrm tell_mm: sending media manager msg: TERMINATE
```

Note: I am able to successfully restore a small datafile size about 1.2GB.

Please if you have such kind of experience help me.
The issue is about restoring big files using Netbackup.

Answer (score 3):

> 7/25/2012 3:27:50 PM - Error bpbrm(pid=1176) socket read failed, An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  (10054)

This shows that it is trying to read from a socket that has been closed. It's a networking problem. Ask your network administrator to raise the firewall connection timeout between the database host and the netbackup host.

Comment: Thank you @Phil I've already told my network administrator to increase socket idle timeout on firewall , waiting his response :) Thank you very much . Because of your answer I am completely sure that this is a network problem. Appreciate your help!